# Find last element with a particular child

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with css... I cannot modify markup/DOM of the page:(

I have this situation:

```
...
<li class=menuitem">
    <a class="level1">...</a>
</li>
<li class=menuitem">
    <a class="level2">...</a>
</li>
<li class=menuitem">
    <a class="level2">...</a>
</li>
<li class=menuitem">
    <a class="level1">...</a>
</li>
```

I must find last li with the level2 child.

How can I do? (I would like to avoid js or jquery)

thanx

Comment: You *will* need jQuery: `$('.menuitem:has(.level2):last')`

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot achieve this with pure CSS

Comment: bad... however thanx :(